# How can I TextView text fly and reach from one place to particular place and also reverse?

Tags: android, animation, textview

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BziOuYi-lh6RUGMxc21sS0xFMDA/view?usp=sharing 
I want to achieve this type of animation in my game application. How can i achieve it and what library is useful to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectAnimation;

```
private void startMove(View targetView, int targetX, int targetY) {
    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(targetView, "translationX", 0, targetX).start();
    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(targetView, "translationY", 0, targetY).start();
}

startMove(numberView, 200, 200);
```

Comment: ObjectAnimator.ofInt doesnt work instead use ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, "translationX", 0, targetX).start();